# Confusion about repeating pattern in python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have confusion about repeating pattern in Python regular expression.
I read from the documentation that '*' means repeating zero to N times. Suppose I have a string `abc123def`. I want to find the position of the substring containing numeric characters, so I use the following code:

```
p = re.compile(r'[\d]*')
p.search('abc123def').span()
```

And it outputs `(0,0)`
If I change the regex to `[\d]+`, it outputs `(3,6)`.

Why the regex `r'[\d]*'` doesn't work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work. `[\d]*` (BTW, brackets are unnecessary - `\d*` will do exactly the same) matches any sequence of digits, **including 0 digits ie. an empty string**. And empty string is matched anywhere, in particular at the beginning of the string. If you want a **non-empty** sequence of digits, use `\d+` like you already did.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, it finds a zero-length string at the beginning of your string.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see what is happening is to use `findall`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d*', 'abc123def')
['', '', '', '123', '', '', '', '']
```

vs

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', 'abc123def')
['123']
```

Or [visually](https://regex101.com/r/B5Ria3/1/) with regex101

The `*` means 'zero or more' at the first opportunity. You have zero digits at the start of the string. A match! And that matches are every character in the string.

Use `+` if you want to match a substring.

Comment: he has noted, and asked the question